Blazor MFA Login using Entra - Setting Session Length
I have a Blazor website that uses MFA loin via Entra and it works fine, what doesn't work is the session time. After 1 hour, the session ends and the user is logged out and forced to log back in. Is there anyway at all to set the session length? I've Google'd myself out trying to find an answer to this.
Below is my code so far in program.cs, some of it is most likely redundent now as I've been adding bits in for testing to see if anything will work! Figured if the session ends after 10 seconds like I'm trying to acheive below, I know I'm onto a winning solution, but it doesnt work.
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
        .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
            .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("MicrosoftGraph"))
            .AddDistributedTokenCaches()
            .AddSessionTokenCaches();
builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(x => {
    x.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
    //x.SlidingExpiration = true; 
});

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

builder.Services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(x => x.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);

builder.Services.AddDbContext<DB>(x =>
    x.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DB"))
    .UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking));

builder.Services.AddMvc().AddSessionStateTempDataProvider();
builder.Services.AddSession(x => {
    x.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
    x.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment()) {
    app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
} else {
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();


app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllers();
app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");

app.Run();


According to the documentation, there is a Access Token Lifetime property, which affect Access tokens, ID tokens, SAML2 tokens, which is 1 hour by default. Note that there are limitations, as the documentation says:

You can specify the lifetime of an access, ID, or SAML token issued by the Microsoft identity platform. You can set token lifetimes for all apps in your organization, for multitenant (multi-organization) applications, or for service principals. We currently don't support configuring the token lifetimes for managed identity service principals.

This page provides information about how a lifetime policy may be defined/changed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/configure-token-lifetimes
It gives this sample code:
Install-Module Microsoft.Graph

Connect-MgGraph -Scopes  "Policy.ReadWrite.ApplicationConfiguration","Policy.Read.All","Application.ReadWrite.All"

# Create a token lifetime policy
$params = @{
  Definition = @('{"TokenLifetimePolicy":{"Version":1,"AccessTokenLifetime":"4:00:00"}}') 
    DisplayName = "WebPolicyScenario"
  IsOrganizationDefault = $false
}
$tokenLifetimePolicyId=(New-MgPolicyTokenLifetimePolicy -BodyParameter $params).Id

# Display the policy
Get-MgPolicyTokenLifetimePolicy -TokenLifetimePolicyId $tokenLifetimePolicyId

# Assign the token lifetime policy to an app
$params = @{
  "@odata.id" = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/policies/tokenLifetimePolicies/$tokenLifetimePolicyId"
}

$applicationObjectId="aaaaaaaa-0000-1111-2222-bbbbbbbbbbbb"

New-MgApplicationTokenLifetimePolicyByRef -ApplicationId $applicationObjectId -BodyParameter $params

# List the token lifetime policy on the app
Get-MgApplicationTokenLifetimePolicy -ApplicationId $applicationObjectId

# Remove the policy from the app
Remove-MgApplicationTokenLifetimePolicyByRef -ApplicationId $applicationObjectId -TokenLifetimePolicyId $tokenLifetimePolicyId

# Delete the policy
Remove-MgPolicyTokenLifetimePolicy -TokenLifetimePolicyId $tokenLifetimePolicyId

See the AccessTokenLifetime property in the code in particular.

In the following steps, you'll create a policy that requires users to authenticate less frequently in your web app. Assign the policy to service principal, which sets the lifetime of the access/ID tokens to 8 hours for your web app.


Create a token lifetime policy.

POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/policies/tokenLifetimePolicies
Content-Type: application/json
{
    "definition": [
        "{\"TokenLifetimePolicy\":{\"Version\":1,\"AccessTokenLifetime\":\"8:00:00\"}}"
    ],
    "displayName": "Contoso token lifetime policy",
    "isOrganizationDefault": false
}


Assign the policy to a service principal.

POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/00001111-aaaa-2222-bbbb-3333cccc4444/tokenLifetimePolicies/$ref
Content-Type: application/json
{
  "@odata.id":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/policies/tokenLifetimePolicies/00aa00aa-bb11-cc22-dd33-44ee44ee44ee"
}


List the policies on the service principal.

GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/00001111-aaaa-2222-bbbb-3333cccc4444/tokenLifetimePolicies


Remove the policy from the service principal.

DELETE https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/00001111-aaaa-2222-bbbb-3333cccc4444/tokenLifetimePolicies/00aa00aa-bb11-cc22-dd33-44ee44ee44ee/$ref

EDIT
As an alternative to the Powershell-based solution I have quoted from the documentation, @jbmintjb found MSAL, another solution, as we can find here. More information can be found here.

Can you try adding this line to your code unless it already has this? app.UseSession();

@SoftwareDveloper it's a PoweShell code taken from the documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/configure-token-lifetimes.

@LajosArpad thank you for your help. Using PowerShell to apply this is something way beyond my comfort zone. However, after the very helpful information you have given me, I have found something called MSAL, which from all accounts handles token refreshing for me, which in turn should solve all my issues! For anyone insterested, its here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/standalone-with-microsoft-entra-id?view=aspnetcore-8.0

@jbmintjb happy to help. And thanks for mentioning MSAL, that's a feasible and good alternative to the Powershell solution. Edited my answer accordingly.
